# Пропадает placeholder в моей WordPress теме

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

В моей WordPress теме пропадает placeholder в виджете поиска. Только в этой теме, и только в этом виджете.

Вот код в теме TwentySeventeen:

```
<input type="search" id="search-form-58d9301f47c6a" class="search-field" placeholder="Поиск…" value="" name="s">
```

А вот в моей:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
```

Так я стилизую этот виджет (less):

```
.widget_search{

  form{
    div {
      position: relative;
    }
  }

  label{
    display: none;
  }

  input[type='text']{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: @graywidg;
  }

  input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    display: block;
    color:@search;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing:1px;
  }
  input::-moz-placeholder          {
    display: block;
    color:@search;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing:1px;}/* Firefox 19+ */
  input:-moz-placeholder           {
    display: block;
    color:@search;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing:1px;}/* Firefox 18- */
  input:-ms-input-placeholder      {
    display: block;
    color:@search;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing:1px;}


  input[type='submit']{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: @gray6;
    color: #fff;
  }

}
```

Как видите, явно указал, чтобы placeholder не скрывался посредством css, но понимаю, что если его нет в html коде, значит, проблема не в css, куда смотреть, где может быть ошибка?

Comment: А где placeholder в html коде? Вы его просто не выводите. И что же хотите увидеть?

Comment: В том то и дело, это стандартный виджет, который я не трогаю вообще, и он работает на моей теме по другому, в отличии от других тем. У меня в этом то и вопрос, почему placeholder не выводиться?

Comment: Это может быть что угодно. Например, там есть js, который добавляет placeholder позже.